# ¿Cómo acceder a un JTextField según su nombre en Java?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, jtextfield

Necesito evaluar varios JTextFields a la vez, por ende, ideo crear un array con los nombres de todas las cajas de texto, y así poder guardar en otro array los valores que contengan cada uno de ellos.

Pero desconozco cómo es que puedo acceder a un JTextField según su nombre, es decir algo como
Where JTextField.name = "Array[i]"

Claramente este es un error vano e incorrecto, pero no sé si es posible, y de serlo cómo es. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Alej, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar un [hashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), donde la clave será el nombre del JTextField y el valor será el propio objeto JTextField:

```
HashMap<String, JTextField> camposDeTexto = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
```

y agregas los JTextField al map de esta manera:

```
camposDeTexto.put("name1", new JTextField());
camposDeTexto.put("name2", new JTextField());
camposDeTexto.put("name3", new JTextField());
```

Si quieres acceder a algún elemento del hashMap podes usar el metodo get() donde pasamos la clave como argumento y nos devuelve el elemento asociado a esa clave:

```
JTextField campo = camposDeTexto.get("name1");
```

finalmente podemos preservar el valor del campo de esta manera:

```
String valorCampo = campo.getText();
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.